# ServiceStack OrmLite - Is it possible to do a group by and have a reference to a list of the non-grouped fields?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

It may be I'm still thinking in the Linq2Sql mode, but I'm having a hard time translating this to OrmLite.

I have a customers table and a loyalty card table.

I want to get a list of customers and for each customer, have a list of express cards.

My strategy is to select customers, join to loyalty cards, group by whole customer table, and then map the cards to a single property on customer as a list.

Things are not named by convention, so I don't think I can take advantage of the implicit joins.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code I have now that doesn't work:

```
query = query.Join<Customer, LoyaltyCard>((c, lc) => c.CustomerId == lc.CustomerId)
    .GroupBy(x => x).Select((c) => new { c, Cards = ?? What goes here? });
```

Edit: I thought maybe this method:

```
var q = db.From<Customer>().Take(1);
q = q.Join<Customer, LoyaltyCard>().Select();
var customer = db.SelectMulti<Customer,LoyaltyCard>(q);
```

But this is giving me an ArgumentNullException on parameter "key."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the description or your example code what you're after, but you can fix your [SelectMulti Query](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#selecting-multiple-columns-across-joined-tables) with:

```
var q = db.From<Customer>()
    .Join<Customer, LoyaltyCard>();

var results = db.SelectMulti<Customer,LoyaltyCard>(q);
foreach (var tuple in results)
{
    Customer customer = tuple.Item1;
    LoyaltyCard custCard = tuple.Item2;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to populate my customer object with a list of loyalty cards. The join works fine, but I only want one record per customer. I'm trying to figure out how to reference the fields in the second table as a List<LoyaltyCard> for each customer I'm grouping by. I was looking at Sql.Flatten, but I don't know how to reference the non-grouped fields in the after the GroupBy method. If this still doesn't make sense I'll edit the question with more visuals.

Comment: @IronicMuffin You'd need to do that via [Reference Conventions and LoadSelect](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions). The Typed `SqlExpression` wraps a SQL Query and its tabular resultset, it doesn't merge results. The `SelectMulti` example above returns the data you need, but you'd need to manually merge the results into the shape you want. Or you could use the [Merge() extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets) to merge results from 2 separate queries.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using the Reference Conventions and LoadSelect. I'm still stuck in the old way of thinking. Thank you for the guidance.